# transform json in rust, similar pandas explode and lamda

Tags: json, struct, rust, serde

I have a json file / object that i need to transform in rust. The transformation is very similar to a vlookup / map reduce job

**input**:

```
{
    "region": "minikube",
    "streams": {
      "stream1": {
        "producers": [
          "user1",
          "user2",
          "user3"
        ],
        "consumers": [
          "user3",
          "user4",
          "user2",
          "user5"
        ]
      },
      "stream2": {
        "producers": [
          "user3",
          "user5",
          "user2"
        ],
        "consumers": [
          "user1",
          "user4"
        ]
      },
      "stream3": {
        "producers": [],
        "consumers": []
      }
    }
  }
```

**result**: (either a csv or json output of every user in the "producer" and "consumer" column with the respective "stream" they can either produce_to or consume_from based on which column they are in)

```
user, produce_to, consume_from
user1, ['stream1'], ['stream2']
user2, ['stream1', 'stream2'], ['stream1']
user3, ['stream1', 'stream2'], ['stream1']
user4, [], ['stream1', 'stream2']
user5, ['stream2'], ['stream1']
```

the equivalent in pandas python looks like this:

```py
# consumers
    consumers_df = stream[['name', 'consumers']].explode('consumers')
    consumers_df = consumers_df.groupby(['consumers']).agg(lambda x: str(x.tolist()))
    consumers_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    consumers_df.rename(columns={'consumers':'user', 'name':'consume_from'}, inplace=True)

# producers
    producers_df = stream[['name', 'producers']].explode('producers')
    producers_df = producers_df.groupby(['producers']).agg(lambda x: str(x.tolist()))
    producers_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    producers_df.rename(columns={'producers':'user', 'name':'produce_to'}, inplace=True)
```

any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Add your example to https://play.rust-lang.org/